# Why isn't there an implicit defaulted definition for pure virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

I know that if the class is supposed to be abstract, but does not contain any used-defined method, there is technique to achieve this by making the destructor pure virtual.

```
class B{
public:
    virtual ~B() = 0;
}
```

As far as I understand the object in example below should not be able to be instantiated.

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
public:
    A(){std::cout<<"A::A()"<<std::endl;}
    virtual ~A() = 0;
};


class B : public A{
public:
    B(){std::cout<<"B::B()"<<std::endl;}
};

int main(){
    B b;
}
```

I know that pure virtual functions also can have definitions, and that in the case above it should be defined for destructor of `B`, but something is obscure to me. Is there any particular reason not to make the definition of pure virtual destructor to be implicitly defaulted in C++ standard, because to me it would make a lot of sense.

Comment: "*Is there any particular reason not to make the definition of pure virtual destructor to be implicitly defaulted in C++ standard*" What would that mean, and why would you want it?

Comment: @NicolBolas That would mean that if there isn't any definition provided for pure virtual destructor, the default definition is used. Regarding to the second question, to me it would make sense, as far as destructors usually have the default implementation, so why make the code to be more dirty by adding definition for it?

Comment: The point of making a function pure virtual is so that derived classes *must define it*. Defaulting it is kind of the opposite of that. So I'm not sure what you would gain over just using `= default` if that's the behavior you want. That is, it's unclear what behavior you're trying to get.

Comment: The reason is probably more syntactic than anything else.   If a destructor is declared (which is necessary to make the destructor pure virtual) generation of a "default" definition is suppressed.   And syntactic rules disallow `virtual ~A() = 0 = default` in the definition of class `A`.    There are quite a few such syntactic gaps in C++, and the answer for why a lot of them haven't been fixed amounts to "it's a minor practical concern and nobody has got around to proposing rules to fix the syntactic concern".

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes I know, but I am only talking only about the case of destructor.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan: Why should a pure virtual destructor be special? Again, the *whole point* of declaring the `virtual` destructor pure is to *force* derived classes to implement it. If you don't want to force them to implement them, you can `= default` them yourself.

Comment: @Peter As far as I understand `virtual ~A() = 0 = default` is making the destructor explicitly defaulted, but I am talking about implicitly default.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan  `virtual ~A() = 0 = default` is not allowed.   The point is that syntactic rules prevent the declaration that a destructor is pure virtual from also being a definition.

Comment: @NicolBolas  I think that the case of virtual destructor could be special because it is used for special case when the class does not have any used-defined methods. In this case it is done in order to prevent direct instantiation of `class B`, not to make the derived classes to implement it, as per to my understanding. However, the implementation of the destructor should be present in order the program to be well-formed.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan: I'm also rather curious as to how often this happens: "*the class is supposed to be abstract, but does not contain any used-defined method*" I can't think of any circumstance where I want a class to be "abstract", but it doesn't actually provide an *interface*. That pretty much makes a mockery of the Liskov substitution principle. The only thing you could do with such a type is employ `dynamic_cast` to convert it to something useful, which is a big code smell at the best of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a function is declared pure virtual, then this means two things:

1. The class with such a declaration cannot be instantiated.
2. Any derived classes must provide a definition for the method, or they also cannot be instantiated.

However, #2 only happens if you don't provide a definition for that pure virtual function declaration. If you *do* define the pure virtual function, then derived classes do not specifically need to override those methods.

Therefore, if there was always a defaulted definition of a pure virtual destructor, it would be *impossible* to force a user to declare a destructor for derived classes.

In the vanishingly rare circumstance where you have a class you intend to use as a virtual type, but has no actual interface (I fail to see how you could uphold the Liskov substitution principle when you have *no interface*) and therefore should not be instantiated, and but you also want a user to not have to define a destructor explicitly, you [can do this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vqcE3MoK5):

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
public:
    A(){std::cout<<"A::A()"<<std::endl;}
    virtual ~A() = 0;
};

A::~A() = default; //Yes, this is legal.


class B : public A{
public:
    B(){std::cout<<"B::B()"<<std::endl;}
};

int main(){
    B b;
}
```

However, I highly doubt this circumstance comes up in reality often enough to actually matter. In most real types intended for use in virtual interfaces, they have actual virtual interfaces beyond "can be destroyed". They need `virtual` destructors, but they also have other virtual functions which can be pure. As such, their destructors don't need to be pure.